# log4j in simple java maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, log4j

I have simple java project. I manage my dependancies using maven. I added log4j dependency in my pom.xml

Now I want to make use of

```
package com.abc.xyz;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(App.class);
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        logger.debug("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

I have my log4j.properties file in resources folder.

When I run App as a Java application I get following error.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.abc.xyz.App).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

So, my question is how to make runtime know that my log4j.properties file is in resources folder.

**EDIT**

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.abc.xyz</groupId>
  <artifactId>learning</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>learning</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

and here is my log4j.properties file

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG
```

Comment: can we see your pom.xml please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified my App class as follows:

```
public class App 
{
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(App.class);
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("/absolute/path/to/log4j.properties");
        logger.debug("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the system property `log4j.configuration` to the runtime path of the file. This can be done in the application launcher. Something like this, assuming your configuration file is in the root of your working directory (since you said your file is in *src/main/resources* maven will move it to the root)

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties
```

But i have to say, if your file is really called log4j.properties and it really is in *src/main/resources* you should not need this since log4j will look for it there by default

Comment: I am using eclipse. I am running App.java as java application.

Comment: In your `Run COnfigurations` for the app, go to the Arguments tab and in the VM arguments section enter the configuration i told you, but point to the actual location of the file

Comment: I tried that. The exact same thing. Even with absolute file path. I am getting same error message.

Comment: then add this property  
-Dlog4j.debug  
this will print some log4j info telling you where he expects the file, among other useful things

Answer (score 2):

You should place log4j.properties under `src/main/resources` folder of your projects to avoid the warning or provide the file path using `-Dlog4j.configuration=<FILE_PATH>`

Answer (score 0):

change your pom.xml dependency for log4j to this:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta9</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta9</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and see if it works